# ChartJS 2 How to globally remove xAxis gridLines?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I'm using chartjs 2, and I'm trying to disable the grid lines on xAxis and enable grid lines on yAxis and make them dashed.

I have achieved this functionality by adding this to my Line graph config;

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
            display: false,
        }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
            display: true,
            borderDash: [2],
            borderDashOffset: [2],
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)',
            drawBorder: false,
            drawTicks: false,
        }
    }]
}
```

However, when I do this, it randomly adds another axis to my chart with completely bogus values. I want to remove this axis and keep the original but also keep the gridLines config.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the defaults for this. You can set it in the `scale` default so it does it for all the chart types and scales. If you specifically want to hide the X axis gridLines only you need to set it on chart type level.

```js
Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.display = false // hides all the gridLines in all charts for all axes
Chart.defaults.line.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines = {
  display: false
} // Hides only the X axes gridLines in all line charts

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Chart.defaults.line.scales.xAxes[0] only has variables 'id' and 'type' for me. Doesn't have 'gridLines' so setting that default isn't possible. Any ideas why these wouldn't be available for me?

Comment: it also isnt available in my stack snippet thats why I set the gridLines to an object because if I would try to set it like this: `Chart.defaults.line.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.display = false` it cant do that since gridLines is undefined. Thats why I do `.gridLines = {}` so it makes the property on the object